# Code Blocks and SDL output. weird behavior

Tags: c++, windows, sdl, codeblocks

I dont know if my codeblocks has something wrong but I can compile the project but I cannot run it from the program itself it flashes and then the SDL aplication closes and the console appear(IDK but this console doesn't seem like the tipic console).

I can go and run the program by myself but seriously is not the way it should be right?

And also I have noticed that when you run a console aplication not SDL aplication the console is slighty different? why, is there a way to solve this? has someting to do with the console?

Comment: What is the message returned by Codeblocks?

Comment: Is something like procces returned 1<0x1> execution time: 1.117 s it normally happens when the windows get closed not by pressing enter also codeblocks output's a a similar message on the compiler log

Answer (score 0):

I assume your using code blocks in windows.
The reason for the difference in the console is because code blocks uses Msys which is a minimal implantation of a POSIX (*nix) shell environment.

Msys treats paths in windows like *nix paths C:\folder\file.ext can be access via /c/folder/file.

MSYS works together with MinGW to provide a *nix like environment and build chain, including GCC, make, auto-conf and a few others, you can also build most open source libraries *fairly* easily in the same way you would on a *nix system: "./configure" "make" "make install".

There are a few things you should check that your doing right when compiling SDL with MinGW.

g++ seems to work better than gcc in my experience.

You need to set up the options going to g++:

```
    -g -O2
```

include Dir:

```
    -I/mingw/include/SDL
```

Defines, you can also replace the -D with #define and put at the top of your source:

```
    -D_GNU_SOURCE=1 -Dmain=SDL_main -DHAVE_OPENGL
```

Lib folder

```
    -L/mingw/lib
```

Libraries:

```
    -lmingw32 -lSDLmain -lSDL -mwindows
```

These setting might not work for you but there pretty close, so check where the SDL.h and lib file is and adjust if necessary. Though those are probably set up right if it is compiling.

Comment: Well i just set it up the same way you will do with Dev-Cpp I just copied linkers on other linker options, I mean it compiles but it doesn't run from the program, for running it I must go to the folder where the .exe is and run it and it runs perfectly but... I cannot male it run from codeblocks wich will save me a lot of time

Answer (score 0):

Its fixed i just had to copy the images to same folder as the project silly of me =P